# Remote MongoDB on EC2 with Spring MVC

Tags: mongodb, spring-mvc, amazon-ec2, remote-access

I deploy MongoDB on Amazon EC2, set up connection, open port 27017 to my IP address.
bind_ip in mongodb.conf on EC2 is set to 0.0.0.0.

From my local IP, with web browser I can assess remote mongodb admin at address xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:28017

If I access xxx.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:27017 with web browser, I get notification

> "You are trying to access MongoDB on the native driver port. For http
>   diagnostic access, add 1000 to the port number"

, indicating that port permission is opened right, I think.

I tried to wire Spring MVC to remote MongoDB instead of localhost with this code:

```
 @Configuration
public class SpringMongoConfig extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    public String getDatabaseName() {
        return "db";
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        return new MongoClient("xxx.compute.amazonaws.com");
    }
}
```

When I tested the API with POSTMAN plugin, the response is always:

> exception": "org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException",
>       "message": "Unable to connect to any server that matches AnyServerSelector{}; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoServerSelectionException: Unable to connect to any server that matches AnyServerSelector{}",

I think the deployed app could not connect to MongoDB somehow. I tried to search but could not find answer. Do you have any idea?

Regards

Comment: Does your Spring MVC code work correctly when connecting to localhost?

Comment: Hi.Spring MVC works perfectly on localhost. Yesterday I figured out that the issue comes from MongoDB on EC2. I do not know why but mongod service keeps restarting itself or freeze. This creates the lost of connection between the app and its DB. A fresh reinstall of MongoDB on EC2 and keep it running continuously on background gets the job done